# PHP - fpassthru() doesn't display image

Tags: php, pdo

I wrote a script to test fpassthru(). The idea is that there's a form to submit image. Once submitted the script would create a file handle for the image at the temporary location on the server. Then the file handle is passed to fpassthru() and is displayed on the webpage. However as I ran this script, the image is not displayed, but rather a small blank square  at the center of the page. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" enctype="mu
ltipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
  $finfo = finfo_open();
  $type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  if(strpos($type, "image")!==False)
  {
    $file=fopen($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "rb") or die("Unable to open file<br>");
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    fpassthru($file);
  }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can't output file data AND HTML. At the moment you're telling the browser that it's to render an image, but the image data contains HTML which makes it invalid.

Comment: Well, it *can*, but not at the same time. You should move that PHP to the very start of the file, and remember to `die();` after outputting the image.

Comment: Okay I moved the PHP part to another file and it worked. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: hng123 consider adding an answer to show your finished result for people finding this question in future

Answer (score 0):

first off, you can't send both the HTML and the image in the same request (well, with a workaround, like base64 encoding the image, it IS possible, but seldom a good idea, such workarounds use significantly more bandwidth and cpu and ram, both for your server and the browser, etc~), either send the upload HTML form, OR the image, not both in the same request, like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
  $finfo = finfo_open();
  $type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  if(strpos($type, "image")!==False)
  {
    $file=fopen($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "rb") or die("Unable to open file<br>");
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    fpassthru($file);
    die();
  }
}
?><html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" enctype="mu
ltipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

second, don't do this: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>"` - not only are you exposing yourself to XSS vulnerabilities, which you TRY to protect against unsuccessfully here with htmlspecialchars() but fail to (for example, try entering the url with `page.php?%27+onmouseover%3D%27alert%28%27vulnerable%27%29%3B%27+`), but is completely unnecessary. when you want to post to the current page, simply completely omit the "action" attribute completely. and when you want to protect against XSS injections, make sure to give htmlspecialchars the appropriate flags, `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED` - htmlspecialchars with those flags would actually protect you from xss injection here. on that note, i've been using this function for many years to protect against xss injection:

```
/**
 * convert any string to valid HTML, as losslessly as possible, assuming UTF-8
 *
 * @param string $str           
 * @return string
 */
function hhb_tohtml(string $str): string {
    return htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );
}
```